# density of the sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ in $(0, \infty)$ with probability densities
$$\frac{\theta_i^xe^{-\theta_i}}{x!}\quad\forall i\in \{1,2\}.$$

Could someone help me to find the distribution of $X_1+X_2$.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ continuous or discrete?

Comment: I am guessing it is discrete - since the person would be asking what $x!$ means for a float.

Comment: Also, that is the probability *mass* function for a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1 + X_2 = t) = \sum_{y = 0}^{t}\mathbb{P}(X_1 = t - y , X_2 = y) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = y) = \sum_{y = 0}^{t} \dfrac{\theta_1^{t -y}e^{-\theta_1}}{(t-y)!}\dfrac{\theta_2^y e^{-\theta_2}}{y!} = $$

$$=e^{-(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}\dfrac{1}{t!}\sum_{y = 0}^{t} \binom{t}{y}\theta_1^{t-y} \theta_2^y = \dfrac{e^{-(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}(\theta_1 + \theta_2)^t}{t!}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.